# How to fix psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I have **django** app and **separate** script folder. Script folder has file that execute `select * from table` from DB which is connected to **Django** app. This scripts working in `While=True`

I am using **docker** and scripts folder , **django** , **postgresql** are separate docker containers. I am restoring data to **Postgresql** container then  making  migrate.

However, I am getting `psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block` this error from script container, `ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block` this error from Postgresql container.

How can I fix it? I have spent whole day could not find anything useful.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
from django.db import transaction, DatabaseError
        try: 
           #code
        except DatabaseError:
            transaction.rollback()
```

did not help.

Comment: `InFailedSqlTransaction` != `DatabaseError`